# Drupal7 Retrieve the values from an array

Tags: arrays, drupal

I have an array, that I want to retrieve the values from. 
When I test the array with a print_r, it says that it has the right values. But when I want to show them  in their right places, it says that it has no values.

```
function employees_items($nodeid, $language)
{
  $query  = db_query(//SOME QUERY);
  $rows   = array();

   foreach ($query as $row) {
    $rows[] = array(
        $row->nid,
        $row->title,
        $row->field_service_nummer_value,
        $row->field_support_email_value,
        $row->uri,
    );
}

    return $rows;
```

}

Here I want to retrieve the values...I want the value in $row->uri. The errormessage: Trying to get property of non-object i employees_block_view()

```
  function employees_block_view($delta = '')
 {
 if (array_key_exists($brandpage_id_page, $medarbejder_brandpages))
    {
     switch ($delta)
    {           

        case 'employees':                                   

        $employees = employees_items($brandpage_id_page, $lang_name);

        foreach ($employees as $row)
            {

              $block['content'] .= '<div class="img">';
              $block['content'] .= '<img style="width: auto; height: 100px;"    src="'.file_create_url($row->uri). '" alt="Vores support medarbejder" />';
   }
  return $block;
 }
```

Comment: The results of your query are correct?

Comment: yes the result of the query are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This is the way it must be written to read the value of 'uri'.

```
 $block['content'] .= '<img style="width: auto; height: 100px;" src="'.file_create_url($row['uri']). '" alt="Vores support medarbejder" />';
```